# Html element's events are not removing while deleting that element

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have some events that are binded in my backbone view.

```
sampleView = Backbone.View.extend({
events: {
              "click .sum": "sumButtonFunc",
              "click .diff": "diffButtonFunc"
        }
sumButtonFunc: function(){
    console.log("sum called")
}
diffButtonFunc: function(){
    console.log("diff called");
}
});
```

this is the HTML Code:

```
<div class="panel">
<button class="sum" type="button">Sum</button>
<button class="diff" type="button">Diff</button>
</div>
```

These buttons are visible when i initialize the model of this.

I am removing these function using jquery.remove() function.

```
this.$el.find('.panel').remove();
```

when at some other place i am again initializing this view, events of these buttons (previous instance's events) are still remains in the context and the event is being fired two times. same is happening if i reinitialize the model third time, events are being fired three times.

how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: <div class="panel">// close your div
<button class="sum" type="button">Sum</button>
<button class="diff" type="button">Diff</button>
</div>

Comment: I'm not familiar with Backbone, but I'd guess that code is setting up delegated event handlers, and you're calling it a second time when adding the new elements. Try just calling it on page load, not when you add new elements afterwards.

Comment: see my answer i hope that is what you want

Comment: Do you have a functional example of you're doing? Something on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com perhaps? Sounds to me like you're sharing one `el` amongst several view instances and not cleaning up after yourself.

Comment: @mu is too short:  yes i am doing same, i have to remove the el/veiw before re-initializing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to destroy the Backbone view before again re-initializing it.
I am not destroying it in my case, so every time when I am again re-initializing it, the context of old view remains their.

we can remove the view by:

```
$el.remove();
```

or

```
var viewOBJ = new sampleView();
viewOBJ.remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

what is the $el of your view?

backbone delegates the events on your $el. When you reinitialize the view, the events are delegated again. (it uses jquery's delegate() method on the $el)

You want to remove your $el completely from the DOM before you reinitialize the view, because delegate will be called again on the same $el. From your code, I think .panel is just part of your view.

An alternative method would be calling [yourView].undelegateEvents() when you unload your view.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete buttons, you are just removing them from DOM, but the event listeners are still present for that class. You have to unbind those events while removing buttons. Everytime you create a view, you are adding listeners for that class, hence each listener will call its callback. This is happening only in this case because you are attaching events for class, where as in other backbone views, you attach event handlers to `this`, so event will be fired only for that element you clicked.

Comment: can you please tell me hoe to unbind the events each time ?I tried $('.panel').children().off(); or $('.panel').children().unbind(), but none of these works for me.

Answer (score 0):

http://backbonejs.org/#View-undelegateEvents

```
    this.$el.find('.panel').remove();
    this.undelegateEvents()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove each event from each element:

```
len = $('.panel').children().length;
for (i= 0; i < len; i++){    
  $('.panel').children().eq(len).unbind();
}
```

You can try too:

```
  $('.panel').off('click','.sum',sumButtonFunc);
  $('.panel').off('click','.diff',diffButtonFunc);
```

**Ps: run this code before deleting the panel, just after removing the event you can delete the panel.**